# Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableArray *__strong' with an expression of type 'SecondViewController *'

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I have to call a value from the first array to the next. But I am getting this message on declaring the array:-

```
SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *_iArray = [second initWithMethod:@"jjsh" :@"jkhfhads"];
```

How can I rectify it to stop my app from crashing ?

Comment: I am not even sure what you are trying to do on the second line...

Comment: Im going to call this array in another view into a second array . +(NSMutableArray*)initWithMethod:(NSString *)firstName :(NSString *)lastName{
    
    NSMutableArray *_iarrySecond = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [_iarrySecond addObject:firstName];
    [_iarrySecond addObject:lastName];
    return _iarrySecond;
}

Comment: Is the second line of the code wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`initWithMethod`: this method has  return type either (id) which will say that it is an initializer of SecondViewController. if your are going to inialize array. then use `NSMutableArray` return type of the method `initWithMethod`

Comment: Yes to initialize an array in the first view and call it in the second view - +(NSMutableArray*)initWithMethod:(NSString *)firstName :(NSString *)lastName{ NSMutableArray *_iarrySecond = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; [_iarrySecond addObject:firstName]; [_iarrySecond addObject:lastName]; return _iarrySecond; }

Comment: try changing the method name by removing init from its name like getValuesWithParametersFirstName .... instead of initWithMethod